# AJAX по выборке из базы данных у слов имеющихся в базе сменить класс

Tags: ajax

Каждое слово на странице это отдельный спан с классом text-for-read
Нужно чтобы функция проверила базу данных и добавила класс к словам, которые были в базе обнаружен

```
function changeclass() {
  var wordstr = document.querySelectorAll('.text-for-read');
  for(var y in wordstr){
  var val = $(wordstr[y]).text();
  $.ajax({
        type:'post',
        url: '../../onclick.php',
        dataType:'json',
        data:'word='+val,
        success:function(data) {
        var i = 0;
            $.each(data, function(index) {
                i++;
                var result = data[index].word;
                console.log(result);//до этой строки все идет по плану и выводит то, что нужно
               (val == result) ? $(wordstr[y]).addClass('colored') : $(wordstr[y]).addClass('nedtr');
//тут я пытаюсь добавить класс к словам, которые были найдены в базе данных, третий стейтмент мне не нужен, но обработчик ругается, поэтому добавляю еще один класс, на деле классы не добавляется.


            });
        }
   });

 }
```

}

Comment: на момент выполнения `(val == result) ? $(wordstr[y]).addClass('colored') : $(wordstr[y]).addClass('nedtr')` переменная `var y` равна длине массива, а не индексу элемента на котором была вызвана.

Comment: используй вместо `var y = $(wordstr[y]).text();` -> `let y = $(wordstr[y]).text();`

Comment: Но признаться, сердце кровью обливается от использованных конструкций, типа `for ... in` по коллекции DOM-элементов и количества запросов, которое вы отсылаете на сервак. Вам сначала нужно собрать все слова в массив, потом отправить его на сервер, там обработать и вернуть уже массив слов, которые нужно выделить. Помните, что вы отсылаете по ajax не только слово, но еще и http-заголовки, а это лишние килобайты для мобильных пользователей, нагрузка на сервак, да и просто это будет в разы дольше. У вас же не web-socket!